# Is there a good way to run benchmark to logstash on GKE?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, logstash, google-kubernetes-engine, benchmarking

Here is an official tool but seems old: https://github.com/elastic/logstash-benchmark-tools

Google provides a way but for security: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/gke-cis-benchmarks-deliver-security-best-practices

Elastic has a tool [Rally](https://github.com/elastic/rally) but for elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/jp/blog/benchmarking-and-sizing-your-elasticsearch-cluster-for-logs-and-metrics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the solution provided by Elastic seems old, I would suggest you to contact the support of Elastic [1] so they can provide you with a more recent approach.

Have a nice day!

---

[1] - https://www.elastic.co/contact?storm=global-header-en